# How to draw a line on the 66th parallel north in ggplot when using a polar (epsg:3995) projection and ggspatial

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, ggspatial

I am trying to draw a blue circle on the 66th parallel north. on a map I am making.

I usually `fortify()` a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and then use the combination `geom_polygon()`, `coord_map("ortho" , ylim = c(50, 90))` and `geom_hline()` to achieve this.

However, for a new project I will have to use `ggspatial::layer_spatial()` on an object that already has a CRS date, so this straight line drawing and automatic re-projection does not work.

This is a demonstration of my usual approach, which works:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_data <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries()
map_data_df <- fortify(map_data)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = map_data_df, 
               aes(x = long,
                   y = lat,
                   group = group),
               col = "black",
               fill = "lightgrey") + 
  coord_map("ortho" , ylim = c(50, 90))  +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 66, col = "blue")
```

[image]

and I am trying to replicate it in this code, but that obviously does not work because the `geom_hline()` does not have the right projection:

```
map_data_transformed <- sp::spTransform(map_data, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3995"))
# needs some fixing to close all the polygons
map_data_transformed <- rgeos::gBuffer(map_data_transformed, byid=TRUE, width=0)


ggplot() + 
  ggspatial::layer_spatial(data = map_data_transformed, 
                           fill = "lightgrey", col = "black", size = .2)+
  coord_sf( xlim = c(-4500000 , 4500000),
            ylim = c(-4500000 , 4500000)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 66, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you?

```
# define parallel north line as a spatial polygon with latitude / longitude projection
new_line <- sp::Polygon(coords = matrix(c(seq(-180, 180),
                                          rep(66, times = 361)), # change this for other
                                                                 # intercept values
                                        ncol = 2))
new_line <- sp::SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(sp::Polygons(srl = list(new_line), 
                                                        ID = "new.line")),
                                proj4string = sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# change projection to match that of data
new_line <- sp::spTransform(new_line, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3995"))

# plot
ggplot() + 
  ggspatial::layer_spatial(data = map_data_transformed, 
                           fill = "lightgrey", col = "black", size = .2) +
  ggspatial::layer_spatial(data = new_line,
                           fill = NA, col = "blue") +
  coord_sf( xlim = c(-4500000 , 4500000),
            ylim = c(-4500000 , 4500000))
```

[image: plot]